# Add Library From Github Android Studio

Tags: android

Hi Guys How i Can Add AndroidRubberIndicator in My Android Studio Project ?

GitHub Link : [Click](https://github.com/LyndonChin/AndroidRubberIndicator)

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow, please read this guide on how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

**File -> New -> Project from version control -> git**

For **Git Repository Url** field add https://github.com/LyndonChin/AndroidRubberIndicator.git

Comment: This is how  people answers when you ask a question like that!